# How to let MSVC compiler optimize multiple step POD initialization?

Tags: c++, optimization, visual-c++, c++17, clang++

I've made this sample code:

```
#include <vector>

struct POD {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    inline static POD make_pod_with_default()
    {
        POD p{ 41, 51, 61 };
        return p;
    }

    inline void change_pod_a(POD &p, int a) {
        p.a = a;
    }

    inline void change_pod_b(POD &p, int b) {
        p.b = b;
    }

    static POD make_pod_with_a(int a) {
        POD p = make_pod_with_default();
        p.change_pod_a(p, a);
        return p;
    }

    static POD make_pod_with_b(int a) {
        POD p = make_pod_with_default();
        p.change_pod_b(p, a);
        return p;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<POD> vec{};
    vec.reserve(2);
    vec.push_back(POD::make_pod_with_a(71));
    vec.push_back(POD::make_pod_with_b(81));
    return vec[0].a + vec[0].b + vec[0].c + vec[1].a + vec[1].b + vec[1].c;
}
```

In the compiled assembly code we can see the following instructions are being generated for the first vec.push_back(...) call:

```
...
mov      DWORD PTR $T2[esp+32], 41 ; 00000029H
...
mov      DWORD PTR $T2[esp+36], 51 ; 00000033H
...
mov      DWORD PTR $T5[esp+32], 71 ; 00000047H
...
mov      DWORD PTR $T6[esp+44], 61 ; 0000003dH
...
```

There's a mov to [esp+32] for the 71, but the mov to [esp+32] for the 41 is still there, being useless! How can I write code for MSVC that will enable this kind of optimization, is MSVC even capable of it?

Both GCC and CLANG give more optimized versions, but CLANG defeats by a large margin with literally no overhead, in a very clean and logical fashion:

CLANG generated code:

```
main: # @main
push rax
mov edi, 24
call operator new(unsigned long)
mov rdi, rax
call operator delete(void*)
mov eax, 366
pop rcx
ret
```

Everything is done at compile time as 71 + 51 + 61 + 41 + 81 + 61 = 366!
I must admit its painful to see my program being computed at compile time and still throw in that call to vec.reserve() in the assembly... but CLANG still takes the cake, by far! Come on MSVC, this is not a vector of volatile.

Comment: Shorter reproducer: `POD make_pod() { POD p = POD{0, 1, 2}; p.c = 3; return p; }`. In that form, MSVC can be made to optimise it by changing `POD p = POD{0, 1, 2};` to `POD p = {0, 1, 2};`. Not sure if there's a similar workaround when the initialiser is a function call's result.

Comment: I believe you meant "changing POD p = POD{0, 1, 2}; to POD p = {0, 1, 3};". The thing is, this sample is a stripped down version of my design. I have readability and design reasons for multiple step initialization: some of the steps are called really later on, or never called. I included an example of the optimization you suggest in my sample so everybody can tell the difference from that to what i need.

Comment: No, `POD p = {0, 1, 3};` is not what I meant. Changing it to `POD p = {0, 1, 2};` and leaving the `p.c = 3;` assignment after it does let MSVC optimise it.

Comment: Of course, if the second step in the real program is conditionally called, or called after other intervening function calls, then this sort of optimization is likely not possible in that case.

Comment: @hvd I've spotted the difference, so for MSVC  "A a = {...};" is not the same as "A a = A{}"?

Comment: But isn't the type automatically deduced? At least intellisense can deduce the same type. @aschepler I'm going to meditate over my code to check if I'm not actually conditionally intializing, you made me doubt about my implementation, but I really believe I'm not missing such an obvious thing. Will report back.

Comment: Nope, I'm not branching anywhere, the branching comes before any initialization. Previous higher level branching results in calls to different "make_pod" functions, which call different combinations of the initialization steps. Each "make_pod" should be fully optimized (by inlining and all the other optimizations). I need the abstraction with zero overhead, as we all know is possible in c++. Let's say my boss will fire me if I don't produce such code.

Answer (score 1):

If you turn your methods `constexpr`, you might do:

```
constexpr POD step_one()
{
    POD p{2, 5, 11};
    p.b = 3;
    return p;
}

constexpr void step_two(POD &p)
{
    p.c = 5;
}

constexpr POD make_pod(){
    POD p = step_one();
    step_two(p);
    return p;
}

POD make_pod_final()
{
    constexpr POD res = make_pod();
    return res;
}
```

resulting to:

```
make_pod_final PROC
    mov      eax, DWORD PTR $T1[esp-4]
    mov      DWORD PTR [eax], 2
    mov      DWORD PTR [eax+4], 3
    mov      DWORD PTR [eax+8], 5
    ret      0
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/g/GBzgEC)

Comment: This one is a nice try and It's clever, and helpful for other stuff I've got, so thank you a ton! But my POD are dynamically allocated in huge containers :( This realization is really important, I will edit my question to better represent my problem tomorrow.

Comment: I now know in a clearer fashion exactly what I need: I need a function which calls other functions, which are inlined, to be optimized again. Sort of a second pass of optimizations. Can MSVC do that? I'm installing CLANG with MSVC integration as an alternative, but I'd rather to remain using MSVC compilers...

Comment: You wouldn't believe what CLANG compiles to...: "mov eax, 9
  pop rcx
  ret" LMAO!